# Foundation 5 - Top Bar - Select into dropdown submenu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I'm having difficulty while adding some custom code (including a simple select, in fact) into a submenu in the TopBar component of Foundation 5+.

The bug is only present in IE11, when the dropdown element is active (ie the submenu is displayed), when i'm trying to select a value from the selectbox, the submenu close itself.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrH2p/4/) in order to reproduce the bug.

```
<ul class="dropdown">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>
<select><option>1</option></select></li>
</ul>
```

(please be sure to be in large screen in order to reproduce it)

In other browsers, the submenu is closed after the select value is set, not while we are choosing it.

Comment: why would anyone what a select in a dropbox!